# UILocalNotification is not getting cancelled

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to cancel a already scheduled notification , notification is getting called but when i try to cancel a notification its not getting cancelled .

NSArray notification contains some random values when there is only one scheduled notification. can anyone help me . I am want to cancel the notification for a particular bookID.

***UPDATE*** :

```
 -(UILocalNotification *)scheduleNotification :(int)remedyID
        {
           NSString *descriptionBody;

           NSInteger frequency;

          UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

            NSLog(@"%d",remedyID);

            descriptionBody =[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];
            frequency = [[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyFrequency"]intValue];

            NSArray *notificationFireDates = [self fireDatesForFrequency:frequency];

            for (NSDate *fireDate in notificationFireDates)
            {
                    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


                    notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                    notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
                    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
                    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

                    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

                    notif.fireDate = fireDate;

                    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notif.alertBody,                                         @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey",  [NSNumber numberWithInt:remedyID],kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,
                                              nil];

                    notif.userInfo = userDict;

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
                }

                return notif;

    }



- (void)cancelNotification:(int)bookID
{
    int notificationBook=0;

        NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

    for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications)
    {
        int notifBookId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationBookIDKey] intValue];


        for (int i=0; i<[bookArray count]; i++)
        {
            notificationBook =[[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"BookID"] intValue];
        }

        NSLog(@"%d",[[notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationBookIDKey]intValue]);

        NSLog(@"%d",notifBookId);

        if (bookId == notifBookId)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you enter into the if loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NSArray notification contains some random values when there is only one scheduled notification.

It may be due to some previously scheduled notifications of that application already exists. Once try to cancel all the notifications of app starts again

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

**Your main problem**

```
- (void)cancelNotification:(int)remedyId
{
NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
NSLog(@"Cancelling... Before %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

  for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications)
  {

  int notifRemedyId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey"]intValue];  // I change the key value

    NSLog(@"remedyID  : %d",remedyId);
    NSLog(@"notifyId : %d",notifRemedyId);
    if (remedyId == notifRemedyId) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
      }
   }

NSLog(@"Cancelling... After %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);


 }
```

The key you have given was wrong. I think that was your problem. I figured out one more thing you are scheduling each notification twice i dont know why. Check with that.

Comment: then when there are two notifications to be fired  then it wont show in locked screen

Comment: I mean cancel all notification only once. After running once you can remove this code(This is for removing the unwanted notification). Then check the notification count is same as the number of notifications you scheduled

Comment: I will try.. share your code.. Put your project in [Drop box](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTMwNzUzNTQ3OQ?src=global9)

Comment: @raptor my mail id..    anil.varghese@robosoftin.com

Comment: I got mail but i didnt find any attachment

Comment: Got dude.. I wil check and get back to you

Comment: I figured out the problem why notification is not canceling, wait i will update my answer

Comment: If you need further help let me know. I cant mail you since i have restriction my company.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];  
if i add that line i wont get any multiple notification ..should i add this line after clean build and remove this line ?

Comment: Ya.. image is disappearing and notification is firing. Check by change your system time. Everything working. But i can say there are some problem regarding notification and setting that indication image

Comment: One thing i noticed u can set notification only for symptoms in section one(image appears only for that) I dont y

Comment: defaultTimeZone is the systemTimeZone only. Did get fired notification? Can clear all notification in __applicationDidFinishLaunch__ for checking

Comment: . In my program the notification is fired for 3 times a day (Morning , afternoon , evening) when i cancel a notification say after morning the notification is not fired for rest of the day (this is the way i want it to perform) ...but the notification is getting fired the next day (morning) .. i think this is where the problem is ...if u r free can u help me

Comment: 3 times per day means you have set 3 notifications for a day. You cannot set custom time intervel for notification. So you need 3 different notifications right??Are you doing in that way? it wont affect the cancellation of single notification.

Comment: i have 3 different notifications...its in for loop in my scheduleNotification Method .. i have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You should move the check the inside the loop

```
for (int i=0; i<[bookArray count]; i++)
{
    int bookId =[[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"BookID"]    intValue];

    if (bookId == notifBookId)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also why you are using the bookArray for count in the loop and remedy array to take out the object